# Low light sporting event

Tags: digital

i have a canon 60 D and a Sigma 24-70 F2.8 plus many more lenses, this was a wrestling event so the focal distance was not an issue, i had my ISO on Auto my speed was on 400 and aperture 3.2 or 2.8, the arena was well lit as it was only a local event my images are not very sharp and as expected heaps of noise in them, i was shooting on continuous and with no flash.

Comment: You've told us what you did and the results. What are you asking?

Comment: Also, a link to examples of your image would be helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to share a few techniques I've used for over 20 years to get better sports images.

Before you arrive, ask yourself what type of a image do you want to see "on film". Far better for you to answer than the camera. With a digital camera you can perfect your ideas in warm up's well before the match happens.

## 1 No Auto-Focus, pre-set exposure and don't let the camera pick the moment.

Your indoors and asking the camera to focus, set exposure and then do it many times in a second. No matter how bright you think it's inside, it's not...that bright. The light value is not changing, so take that job away from the camera. Also when you shift into "continuous mode" your making things worse, not better. Your stacking the deck against a good image.
The camera doesn't know and can't anticipate the decisive moment in the match or a wrestlers take down hold on another wrestler. Find a mid-point on the mat to focus on and get ready to shoot. With the auto focus and exposure delay gone the camera can just open and close the shutter. Something it does well.

## 2 Create a "Focus sand-box" for your subjects to play in.

To help with fast focus. Use depth of field to your advantage. When the subjects are in a confined space, like a wrestling mat, use a smaller f-stop. Instead of F2.8 that's unforgiving, use F8 or F11. With the 24-70 mm lens your not going to isolate the subject from the background anyway so might as well get the entire 20' wrestling mat in focus. To me, a sharp focus image that's grainy, is far better then a out of focus image that has no grain. Subject focus first, then exposure quality second. In fact, sometimes grain helps sell the intensity of the event! So crank up that ISO to 3200! Finally, if you know and can "hyper-focal-focus" the lens, do it. In doors it works great, use the force Luke!

## 3 Fill flash - not complete flash.

I know you said you didn't use a flash. You might have been told "no flash" for this event. Concerts are the same way. That's fine. If not, use some fill flash at a reduced level to help freeze the edge of you subjects. Prior to the event...find out what amount of flash power is needed to be just one third of a stop less than the ambient light value. This will help to sharpen the subjects, without taking over the photo with flash.

## 3 Distance to subject

If the event staff will let you get closure to the mat and use the 24 mm, do it. All these ideas get better the closer to the subject you are.

Cheers,
Scott-

Answer (score -4):

If the arena was well lit, and you were shooting around f2.8, you shouldn't have gotten too much noise in your images. Did you check the settings your pictures were taken at afterwards to see what ISO your camera chose?

Remember f2.8 is not technically f2.8 on an APSC sized camera, you have to multiply it times Canon's 1.6x crop factor to get the real f stop you were at.

Comment: f-number is a property of a lens (basically focal length divided by lens diameter). Can you explain how it is dependant of the camera ? What is the *real* f stop for you ?